# "kubectl get all --all-namespaces" has different output against the same cluster

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl

So when I run `kubectl get all --all-namespaces` on different machines, I get different output and I can't understand why.

First machine (output trimmed for brevity):

```
kube-system         po/kubernetes-dashboard-5569448c6d-w2bdb                                1/1       Running   0          16h
kube-system         po/service-mesh-traefik-5bb8d58bf6-gfdqd                                1/1       Running   0          2d
kube-system         po/tiller-deploy-78d74d4979-rh7nv                                       1/1       Running   0          23h
```

Second machine:

```
kube-system         kubernetes-dashboard-5569448c6d-w2bdb                                1/1       Running     0          16h
kube-system         service-mesh-traefik-5bb8d58bf6-gfdqd                                1/1       Running     0          2d
kube-system         tiller-deploy-78d74d4979-rh7nv                                       1/1       Running     0          23h
```

Ideally, I would like the output from the first machine, with the resource type prefixed to the ouput. Trying to comprehend the output of `get all` without it is extremely frustrating and due to the nature of the words in what I am searching for, it is even more frustrating trying to use Google to search for "get all".

What is different? The cluster is the same, so it should be returning the same data. The first machine is kubectl version 1.9.2, second machine is 1.10.0. The cluster is running 1.8.7.

Comment: The answer is implicit in your last paragraph. There was apparently a change in the output format in `kubectl get`, see [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/cmd/resource/get.go), but I didn't find a note in the release notes :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer lies in the details you mentioned above. The difference in kubectl version displays in different output format between the two machines.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really weird thing to revert. The output is so helpful I don't understand why it would be removed in a newer version. Reverting to the same, older, version produces the output I desire.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally there is this bug: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151